# C++/CLI: How to control WinForms from main function?

Tags: winforms, interface, c++-cli

I'm trying to implement interface controls in main function instead of forms' headers. I'm trying that because I have to work with multiple forms, call one from another and conversely, transfer information between them.
For example, I have button1 in MyForm, and in MyForm's header I do stuff with it by the code:

`private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        //stuff
    }`

How can I do the same from the main function? What I should include, what namespaces to use, and how the code will look like? My main .cpp is now looks so:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array < String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(0);
    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You just don't.  Winforms controls you.  Or rather, the user controls what happens.  The non-modal event-driven nature of GUI programming is fundamentally different from what you know about C++ and console mode apps, you'll have to climb the learning curve.

Comment: So I can do all the stuff only in the forms' headers? Then, how can I, for example, call second form from the first, and then again call first form from second? I read that it can be implemented in main function only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI is still C++ and not C#: You can implement your form's methods in the .cpp rather than in the class definition. It's just not what the wizards do for you.

```
//MyForm.h

namespace Project1
{
    class MyForm
    {
        //...

        //Somewhere in the MyForm class definition
        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);
    };
}
```

And in the cpp:

```
//MyForm.cpp
using namespace System;

namespace Project1
{

    Void MyForm::button1_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
        //stuff
    }

}//namespace Project1
```

---

As for your matter of communicating between multiple forms, you can choose a more Document/View (or Model/View/Controller) approach, by putting your state in a shared object that provides events when modified, and having your forms listen to these events to update themselves when state is changed.